# ConvLSTM, Regression or Classification?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

Is [Next-Frame Video Prediction with Convolutional LSTMs](https://keras.io/examples/vision/conv_lstm/) a regression problem or a classification?

- Why regression/classification?
- Why do we use the last Conv3D layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would consider closer to a regression problem than a classification problem since it's inputs are all the previous frames from which it learns the trend or function to fit, in this case learns the direction in which the MNIST digit might be moving and then predicts the next best possible location.
   Since, it is NOT trying to classify a set of available digit postions as `next_location` or `NOT_next_location`, it doesn't seem like a classification problem.
2. The last layer defined as:

```
x = layers.Conv3D(filters=1, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation="sigmoid", padding="same")(x)
```

Is essentially taking in all past 2D-frames(individual MNIST images), so it's `(height,width,frame_num)` and compressing them to predict the next single frame.

IF you go to the colab notebook link in the keras tutorial you mentioned, you can first 4 cells and add a `model.summary()` to see this:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, None, 64, 64, 1)  0         
                             ]                                   
                                                                 
 conv_lstm2d (ConvLSTM2D)    (None, None, 64, 64, 64)  416256    
                                                                 
 batch_normalization (BatchN  (None, None, 64, 64, 64)  256      
 ormalization)                                                   
                                                                 
 conv_lstm2d_1 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, None, 64, 64, 64)  295168    
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_1 (Batc  (None, None, 64, 64, 64)  256      
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 conv_lstm2d_2 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, None, 64, 64, 64)  33024     
                                                                 
 conv3d (Conv3D)             (None, None, 64, 64, 1)   1729      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 746,689
Trainable params: 746,433
Non-trainable params: 256
```

`conv3D` layer here will output a single prediction frame of dimensions `(64,64,1)`

Connor shorten has made a video explanations as well: [Youtube Tutorial Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P5yv8HDFc_M&ab_channel=ConnorShorten)

Comment: Well explained. 
1) But Convolution operations output feature map right? So you are saying that the last Conv3D is merging all the feature maps produced from ConvLSTM layer?
2) Why the code uses binary cross entropy as loss function if it is not doing classification?

Comment: 1) Essentially yes! It's reducing the dimensionality (specifically over the time domain, where we see at t=0 input was frame1, t=1 -> frame2...so on)                                   
 2) Classification models usually require binary_cross_entropy loss but the reverse isn't always true. Here, the Network is try to approximate a regression problem via means of classification. So yes, Cross entropy loss can be used in regression (although it isn't common.)

Comment: 1) How does it calculates loss then for binary cross entropy, Like pixel value differences of prediction vs ground truth?
2) And ground truth/ Y labels are the shifted frames created from ```create_shifted_frames``` function?

Comment: 1) It is a log loss calculation between the predicted frame and the next frame. It is explained both in the video(Timestamp: 9:29) I mentioned in my answer and in the colab notebook from keras tutorial link in your question 2) Yes. Since we want to predict the next frame based on previous frame, groud_truth or Y is the next frame.

Comment: So let's say Y is the label and p(Y) is the predicted probability in log loss formula. Let's say the predicted and next frame are 3x3, How log loss will be calculated then? Will the corresponding pixels be used like for all 9 pixels of predicted and next frame by plugging them in log loss and then average of all nine loss will be the loss for that frame?